# python rasberry pi syntax error in relay board code

Tags: python

hi Guys I am new to any python scripting. Understand some basics. My issue is i have a Rasberry Pi 2 Model b. and I am trying to control a 8 channel relay like the one used in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oaf_zQcrg7g   . I am trying to follow the same code to try and get it to at least light up and switch some relays. the code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# init list with pin numbers

pinList = [2, 3, 4, 17, 27, 22, 10, 9]

# loop through pins and set mode and state to 'low'

for i in pinList: 
    GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT) 
    GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)

# time to sleep between operations in the main loop

SleepTimeL = 0.2

# main loop

try:
  while True:

    for i in pinList:
        GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(SleepTimeL);
        GPIO.output(i, GPIO.LOW)

    pinList.reverse()

    for i in pinList:
        GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(SleepTimeL);
        GPIO.output(i, GPIO.LOW)

    pinList.reverse()

# End program cleanly with keyboard
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print "  Quit"

  # Reset GPIO settings
  GPIO.cleanup()

# find more information on this script at
# http://youtu.be/oaf_zQcrg7g
```

I have changed inputs to suit the pins i'm using ( 1-9) i have not used ( 1-9) instead of just in case anyone thinks that :).

the error i get:
Hoping i am doing it right, After using:

```
python test.py
```

the error is:

```
File "test.py", line 1 Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11) 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any response would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, what's the problem you have?

Comment: Please post the actual error you're getting, otherwise we won't know how to help you.

Comment: Hoping i am doing it right, After using: python test.py  the error is: File "test.py", line 1
    Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11) 
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: script taken from https://github.com/skiwithpete/relaypi/blob/master/8port/script2.py

Comment: The code above is `test.py`? The syntax error suggests that the first line is `Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11)`, rather than the shebang shown above.

Comment: SiHa you nailed it on the head, when i open up python3 shell command that text that is the syntax error is a default message that I did not even notice, after removing, my code worked now my relay is operational thank you